# select elements multiple of 3 in parent element

Tags: css, css-selectors

is there a way to select with css, elements which have the index multiple of 6 inside a parent element?

for example, in this case i want to choose only multiple of 3:

```
<div>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p> <!--to select -->
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p> <!--to select -->
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p> <!--to select -->
</div>
```

Comment: Don't get multiples of 6 and multiples of 3 mixed up... not every multiple of 3 (3, 6, 9, 12...) is a multiple of 6 (6, 12, 18, 24...).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [`:nth-child(n)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg721782%28v=expression.40%29.aspx):

```
p:nth-child(3n) {
  background: red
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/azehum/4/edit

This method works in IE9+ (source: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3)). If you need support in older browsers, you could use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) to select the elements and add a class to them:

```
$("p:nth-child(3n)").addClass("redbg");
```

Comment: Additionally I would recommend [this link](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/understandingnthchildexpressions#understandingnthchildexpressions__tbl_resultsetsfornthchildpseudoclassexpressions) that as a nice table with Result Sets for Pseudo-class Expressions!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `nth` selector in css

```
p:nth-child(6n) {/*css here*/}
```

[see more here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html)